# What does "new_active_users" field represent?

Tags: support, api

I'm working with some site data obtained via the Stack Exchange API and I see each site has a field called `new_active_users`. I looked at the [type `info`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/info) page for site data, as well as [usage of `/info`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info) pages in the API documentation but neither contains any information about the meaning of that field.

Can you please explain what is the meaning of `new_active_users` field and how the data is aggregated to arrive at this number?