# What broke the API on Jan 13 and Jan 14, 2017?

Tags: bug, status-completed, api

**Update:** see bottom for new information, this isn't a fix for anything but the API is actually broke again on further investigation.

---

Full disclosure: I scrape a bunch of data (non-protected, things that don't require **user** authentication for) out of the API every night.

Often times I [find patterns in this data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288823/what-happened-on-december-9-and-10-2016) and report them here if they are significant or my comrade [finds issues with the documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289834/what-does-new-active-users-field-represent) and we report them as well.

I found another pattern recently in the data-of-my-data or the meta-data of the meta-data (since my data is *already* meta-data).

I log how long it takes to complete API requests (because it's important to know, I have things that use a specific timing and I need to know when it's time to adjust my timing) and I found this interesting characteristic of the API requests:

```
Start   End Time Taken  Total Requests  Requests / Second   Milliseconds / Request  Sites Loaded    Milliseconds / Site Backoff Count   Backoff Seconds End Quota
2017-01-16 00:00:24 2017-01-16 00:05:30 0:05:05 2269    7.42    134.69  324 943.23  8   80  8875
2017-01-15 00:00:11 2017-01-15 00:05:02 0:04:51 2269    7.79    128.42  324 899.35  7   70  9182
2017-01-14 00:00:48 2017-01-14 00:05:48 0:04:59 2269    7.57    132.18  324 925.68  8   80  8792
2017-01-13 00:00:57 2017-01-13 00:08:26 0:07:28 2269    5.06    197.52  324 1383.25 9   90  8141
2017-01-12 00:00:35 2017-01-12 00:07:35 0:06:59 2269    5.41    184.99  324 1295.52 7   70  8358
2017-01-11 00:00:40 2017-01-11 00:08:12 0:07:32 2269    5.02    199.21  324 1395.11 8   80  8149
```

If you pay close enough attention (data is tab-separated, you can drop it in Excel / whatever if you like) you see that the times change somewhat drastically between the 13th and the 14th. They go from a consistent 7 minutes (maybe add 30 seconds sometimes) to a consistent 5 minutes. What caused the drop of two minutes off my request time?

You can also see that my backoff counts and whatnot haven't changed a bit, I'm getting 7-8 backoffs a night on average, and have been for months. (At most I've gotten 11 backoffs, the fewest has been 6.)

I've verified the data (twice now, because this bothered me) and everything is good, so something caused my 2269 requests (always the same number unless [`/badges/name` goes down again](https://stackapps.com/questions/7064/bug-with-badges-name-endpoint)).

The only other information I see that might be pertinent is that on Jan 12, 2017, the API revision changed so I assume it's something to do with a change on the SE side:

```
Gathered    ApiRevision
2017-01-16 00:02:39.1231102 2017.1.11.24452
2017-01-15 00:02:15.3911888 2017.1.11.24452
2017-01-14 00:02:52.5475485 2017.1.11.24452
2017-01-13 00:03:55.9381213 2017.1.11.24452
2017-01-12 00:03:14.5476025 2017.1.11.24452
2017-01-11 00:03:44.5318892 2017.1.3.24329
```

Any information would be greatly welcome, it doesn't affect me much (just decreases my compute time, which is nice) but it does not give me warm fuzzies inside to see such a drastic change when I changed absolutely nothing about what I'm doing. I've also verified with the provider of the server I reside this information on that they didn't change anything either, and they confirmed that my stack is the exact same as it has been.

---

As it turns out, further investigation revealed that the API is currently throwing a `500 Internal Server Error` on the `/badges/name` endpoint again. (Apparently catching exceptions is *way* faster than getting the actual data from that endpoint.) I didn't notice because I don't currently use that data for anything. Seems to only happen when I set `pagesize=100` (a completely valid parameter and value).

Previous bug report: [Bug with `badges/name` endpoint](https://stackapps.com/questions/7064/bug-with-badges-name-endpoint)

Comment: Is the API involved with Microsoft's ASP.NET in some way?

Comment: @AnthonyPham Which portion, mine or the SE side?

Comment: Both if possible. The SE side preferbably

Comment: @AnthonyPham From what I understand SE is an entirely Microsoft shop, the version number is consistent with the Microsoft numbering scheme as well, so the API should be ASP.NET. My side is gathered by a .NET Service on a server that runs each night at 00:00:30UTC+00:00 +/- 30 seconds. This server has no ASP.NET infrastructure on it, and dumps the data directly to a separate SQL server, which provides the data to a third server which is my ASP.NET server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, this finally got solved.

Apparently, it's *heavily* related to [the Census badge being awarded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341928/4564272) recently and that broke the API for some reason.

I confirmed a few minutes ago that this endpoint is fixed, we'll see how the time updates stack up tonight when the automatic run occurs.

Comment: It might be due to the tons of badges given...

Comment: @AnthonyPham SE told me it required an API rebuild to fix it. I'd bet that it wasn't prepared to handle a new badge.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a shot to the Moon, but I'll try even though I have probably no idea about your side or SE's API.

Stack Exchange's API is ASP.NET as you have mentioned in your comment. So while scanning around, zaq posted a comment in chat linking to *Nick Craver's Twitter account*. Conveniently, he is a SE developer and says miscellaneous things related to programming and some HTML stuff. While  <del>stalking him</del> , I mean looking at his tweets on January 14, I found a miracle (I hope):

[image]

He first tweets something about the "MiniProfiler" then cleaning the stacks and ***the lack of StackTrace() which was a API oversight fixed in 2.0***. I'm not quite sure how the stacks and "MiniProfiler" are related to the API but maybe there was some minor new update where the fixture of the `StackTrace()` was reversed. The rendering of the "MiniProfiler" could have caused Nick Craver to clean the stacks and complain about `StackTrace()` though.

Or simply blame SQL and not using enough jQuery...

[image]

Comment: Reviewing his tweets, I found: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/819537688890056704 Perhaps there was something *really* ugly in the SQL that the API was using?

Comment: @EBrown It is SQL after all

Comment: I mean, I have had *my* fair share of not-fun times with SQL server. It really can be a d...pain sometimes.

Comment: @EBrown See my edit :)

Comment: What do you mean by "complains a lot of coding"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'll fix that

Comment: @AnthonyPham As it turns out, the API is currently throwing an error for `/badges/name` again, I don't use the data collected from that endpoint so I didn't even notice. Grrr.