# Badges loading broken in election statistics

Tags: bug, badges, election-page

We have an [current election running](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#christianity.stackexchange) and I noticed the badges are not loading in the election statistics like they should be. It just hangs forever loading badge information:

[image: hung loading badge information]

Unfortunately I blew off reporting this for a couple days figuring it would resolve itself, but it doesn't seem to be a temporary problem.

Comment: Client side JS error, so *should* be easy to fix for the team.

Comment: Yes, `Noteworthy Badges` are not loaded

Comment: Will take a look here shortly after I get some coffee

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289872/what-broke-the-api-on-jan-13-and-jan-14-2017

Answer (score 8):

Ugh! The API is [misbehaving](https://stackapps.com/questions/7064/bug-with-badges-name-endpoint) and caused the site to cull the badges list, so I removed the `pagesize` parameters from those calls, but we're still not getting the full list of badges for some reason (possibly the API calling code not respecting the unusually high `backoff` for that route)…so I threw in a null check to at least avoid the error, since that data is only used for the tooltips anyway.

There's a slew of reliability improvements that I intend to make when I have time, but the tl;dr is that it should be working again, for now. Apologies for the disruption.

Comment: Can we *perhaps* get the API fixed? I have been having this issue [for several days now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289872/what-broke-the-api-on-jan-13-and-jan-14-2017). :(

Comment: I mean, I'd certainly like that too, but unfortunately I have no control over that :(

Comment: Whoops, for some reason I thought you were Tim Post...my bad.

Comment: Many, many people make that mistake, so no worries ;)

Comment: Well, even Tim Post can't fix the API, he's not a developer. ;-)

Comment: Tim - can you use the badge counts returned by the default user object filter to populate the badge counts here? (re: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291331/moderator-candidate-statistics-badge-count-is-zero-in-the-elections-stack-exch)

Comment: @Tim is this fixed, or is there still some problem with the API?