# Moderator candidate statistics - badge count is zero in the elections stack exchange

Tags: bug, badges, election, election-page

In the [Elections](http://elections.stackexchange.com) page for the moderator candidate statistics, the badge counts are displaying as zero.

For an example, in the recent [Travel SE election site](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#travel.stackexchange) the badge counts for main and meta sites are displaying as 0 for gold/silver/bronze.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Election badge count as zero]

Comment: There is a bug in the API, previously it caused the whole page to break, as a workaround they just disabled the badge reading so that the rest will show up.

Comment: @ShadowWizard curious. The list of badges appears to work (even if potentially truncated) as there's noteworthy and tag badges displayed. The badge counts are normally returned as part of the user object so not sure why that can't be used to populate the main/meta badge counts instead of having to have a complete list or whatever the script does...

Comment: @Jon not using the API myself, so not sure about that... try asking Tim (Stone) on his answer to the other report.